# Sublime Text 2 for Plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, sublime-text

I'm currently working on a project that requires plain TeX, not LaTeX. Is it possible to configure Sublime Text 2 to compile plain TeX?

Comment: Isn't Sublime Text 2 a general text editor, and so not tied to LaTeX at all?

Comment: It is a very general text editor, but you can configure it to do tons of different things, LaTeX being one of them. I can use WinEdt for this project, but I'm finding that the white background is just killing my eyes over time. To be honest, I've fiddled with the setting in WinEdt enough to make me go cross-eyed, and I still can't change the background to a darker color (and I know for a fact that's just User Error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell there's no (default) build system for plain TeX. However, as Joseph Wright already said, you can build your own: just make one using Tools > Build System > New Build System... Here's mine, using XeTeX:

`XeTeX.sublime-build`:

```
{
    "cmd": ["xetexmk", "$file_base_name"],
    "path": "$PATH:/home/mk/.bin",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]+): ([0-9]*)([^\\.]+)",
    "selector": "text.tex"
}
```

(I needed to add my own PATH to `"path"`, as Sublime Text (3) didn't read the path settings in my `.bashrc`. If someone knows a solution to this, please tell me.)

`xetexmk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
xetex "$1"
[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit $?;
evince "$1.pdf"
```

This script only calls `evince` if TeX runs correctly. You can of course customize all this to create a better output in the output buffer, like LaTeXing does, but so far this suits my needs.